# Maths question regarding union of multiple sets

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

The question is as follows,

Suppose $A_1, A_2, \ldots A_{30}$ are thirty sets having 5 elements each and $B_1, B_2, \ldots B_n$ are $n$ sets having 3 elements each

Let $$\bigcup_{i=1}^{30}A_{i} = \bigcup_{j=1}^{n}B_{j} = S$$ and each element of $S$ belongs to exactly 10 of the $A_i$'s and exactly 9 of the $B_j$'s, then find the value of $n$.

In the solution since the total number of elements in $A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3, 
\ldots A_{30}$ is 150. The following equation is given

$$S = \frac{30 \times 5}{10} = 15$$ where does this come from and what does the 15 even mean is it the number of elements in the set if so why>

Comment: If you were to list out all the elements of $A_1,A_2,$ etc. *with* repetition you would get $30\times 5=150$ listing of elements.  Now $S=\cup A_i$.  That means every element of $S$ is in an $A_i$ and all elements of all the $A_i$s are in $S$.  So the list of all the elements of $A_1,A_2...$ listed many times will include all the elements of $S$.  And as each element of $S$ is listed *exactly* $10$ times, then that listing of the $150$ elements of all $A_i$ will have each element of $S$ repeated $10$ times.  That means the number of unique elements of $S$ must be $\frac {150}{10}=15$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you are counting pairs of the form $(A_i,x)$ with $x\in A_i$, $i\in 1,\cdots, 30$.  You can count the number of such pairs two ways:

1. There $30$ choices for $i$ and for each such choice there are $5$ choices for $x$.  Thus there are $30\times 5$ such pairs.
2. There are $|S|$ choices for $x$, and for each such choice there are $10$ choices for $i$. Thus there are $|S|\times 10$ such pairs.

Equating the two, gives the equation in the solution:

$$30\times 5= |S|\times 10,$$

which rearranges to $$|S|=\frac{30\times 5}{10}=15$$

The reason this is stated without much explanation is it is a fairly common trick when comparing the size of two sets, where an element of the first set and an element of the second may be in some sense "incident" to each other.  In this case $A_i$ and $x$ are incident if $x\in A_i$.

Note you can use exactly the same trick again to find $n$.  I suggest you do this before looking at the rest of the solution.

Answer (score 1):

How many total elements do you get from sets $A_i$'s if you do not consider the equality of elements? The answer is $30\times 5=150$. Now, note that $$\bigcup_{i=1}^{30}A_i=S$$
and every element in $S$ occurs in exactly $10$ different $A_i$'s.

We are interested in the size of $S$, so we look at the total elements we get from sets $A_i$'s but take into consideration uniqueness of these elements. We can form groups of size $10$ among those $150$ elements such that each group has the same element repeated $10$ times.

Hence, total number of unique elements in $S$ are $150/10=15$. Similarly for the set $B_i's$, you have total number of elements without uniqueness consideration $=3n$. With uniqueness consideration, the total number of elements in $S$ is $\frac{3n}{9}$.

You have two different values for the number of unique elements in $S$. Equating them, you get
$$\frac{30\times 5}{10}=\frac{3n}{9}$$